# aws iot subscribe with php sdk?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-php-sdk

I've implemented the aws-sdk for php / laravel.
I am able to publish messages without any issue using the below code, but I can't seem to find anywhere how I can actually subscribe to that topic and see the response received from the IoT device, any help would be greatly appreciated!

I thought the 'retain message' functions might contain that info, but it only contains the data sent/published, not the response.

Many Thanks

```
        $iot = \AWS::createClient('iotdataplane');
        $result = $iot->publish([
            'payload' => $request->message,
            'retain' => false,
            'qos' => 1,//1,
            'topic' => $request->topic // REQUIRED
        ]);
```

Comment: Does this seem to match what you are trying to achieve? Have you tried taking a look at the suggested solution of using the `Device Shadow Service`? 
RE: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=257022

Comment: hello, Roy, I am also trying to implement IoT but I couldn't find the IoT package for PHP. can you please share with me the package link which you are following as you have mentioned in your above question?

Comment: also if you can provide me the documentation link that will really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if this is what you are trying to achieve but hopefully it helps!

***Device Shadow Service***: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-thing-shadows.html

> If one of the actors in your system is constrained to PHP only, I recommend checking out the `device shadow service` of AWS IoT. Your other actors can publish messages to a shadow topic which gets persisted by AWS IoT. It may not be ideal, though your PHP actor can poll the shadow value over HTTP to check for changes.

***Source***:https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=257022

Otherwise, please provide some more clarification into what you're trying to do and I'll try and edit my answer!

Comment: I basically need the equivalent of the python code in mqtt section on this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/sdk-tutorials.html#sdk-tutorials-prepare